# Generate a random number in C

Tags: random

I am trying to generate a random number, but it should not be a particular number. So i am passing the number which should not be the random number and the range in which it has to be generated to the function, and i am reinvoking the function if the random number generated is the number, which should not be generated, so this is taking a long time and resulting in termination of my program. I am using the following code, let me know how effecient i can generate the random number without waiting for long or even without reinvoking the function.

here rank1 is the number passed to it, which should not be generated and size1 is the number, denoting the range of the maximum accepted value

```
int rgenerator(int rank1, int size1)
{

    int iseed, k;
    time_t seconds;
    time(&seconds); 
    iseed=(unsigned int) seconds;

    srand(iseed);

    k=rand()%size1;

    if(k!=rank1)
        return k;
    else 
        rgenerator(rank1,size1);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard caveat applies here: you want to call `srand` exactly *once* during initialization, and never call it again.

As for not generating `rank1`, I think I'd just reduce the range by 1, and then if the result you get is >= to `rank1`, add one to it to create a "hole" at `rank1`.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1. You don't need to `srand()` every time.  You really shouldn't seed it more than once during the running of a program anyway.  Put this early in your `main()` method, or create a static flag here and only seed it once.
2. Because `time()` gives seconds, `srand` will re-seed the generator to the *same* state every time it's called during the same second, which (especially with this recursion) could be thousands to millions of times, returning the same random number.  Note that recursion will produce a stack overflow (potentially part of your problem) after ~5,000 levels of recursion.  Therefore:
3. Change the recursion to a `while` loop.
4. What kind of size are your `rank1` and `size1` going to be?  If, e.g. `size1`  is RAND_MAX and `rank1` is zero, you ought to be fine.  If, however, `size1` is 1 and rank1 is 0, you can never return.

This might be a better implementation:

```
int rgenerator(int rank1, int size1) {
    // Prevent division by zero.
    assert(size1 > 0);

    // Prevent infinite loops from no valid returns
    assert(rank1 != 0 || size1 > 1);

    int randnum;
    do {
        randnum = rand() % size1;
    } while (randnum != rank1);

    return randnum;
}
```

Now comments on this code:

1. There are more... terse... ways to write that loop, but this way should be the most understandable.
2. You should probably change the asserts to return zero if you haven't learned them yet.
3. You could also produce `size1 - 1` numbers and split them so as to skip `rank1`, but I'll leave that code as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: They stop the program there if the condition is false.  Very useful for debugging, but as I said, at your level you should just change `assert(x)` to `if(!(x)) return 0;` or even return -1 and check for that error condition in the code calling this method.